# Stuck with Compass and Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, css, sass, zurb-foundation

I want to quickly develop front end with Foundation 5. I have already downloaded and use it in my project.

Now I want to be able to edit it. I understand I have to do it with Sass and I have chosen compass.

I have been able to download Compass, Sass, Ruby, Node.js, etc. And after testing everything works fine and I have already done some tests.

I am now stuck in using Compass and Foundation and editing the Foundation files and I request some help.

This is my current project created with foundation on the command line.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rD7L4.jpg

Now I need to start using compass with this in order to modify the CSS files with sass.

Any help shalt be appreciated.

Comment: Why has my original post been edited? What's wrong with my original txt?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a default page you can now rename and change the bits and pieces of :-)

To use SASS (and Compass) and Foundation you create any styles you want in a *new* file called _overrides.scss in the same directory as app.scss with the text editor of your choice and tell compass to watch this directory (*cd* into your site root first)

```
compass watch -s compressed
```

Compass will then tell you it's 'polling for changes' and overwrite app.css [note, Compass is smart enough to work out that this lives in a different directory, 'stylesheets']